# Examples of empty affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations, affine-varieties

The nullstellensatz says that a system $S$ of polynomial equations $f_1=0,f_2=0,…f_n=0$, where $f_i$ are elements of a polynomial ring over a field $K[x_0,x_1,…]$, will have a non-empty affine variety iff every polynomial in the sistem belongs to a proper ideal $I\subset K[x_0,x_1,…]$. The negation of the theorem says that if $S$ has no solution (and thus, $V(I)=\emptyset$), then $I$ is not a proper ideal, or putting it as Wikipedia states: “*there exists $p_0,p_1,…,p_n$ such that $p_0f_0+p_1f_1+…+p_nf_n=1$*“.
So far i understood the theorem, but I can’t seem to find a sistem $S$ with $V(I)=\emptyset$. Is there any example of a non-trivial $S$ with empty affine variety that you know of?

Edit: Maybe i can’t find any because i presume the elements of $K[x_0,x_1,…]$ can have a constant/independent term (example, $x+y-3$). If it is the case, let me know in the answer.

Comment: There is always the $(0,0,0,\ldots)$  affine point. Do you mean projective variety? If so $x+y=0,x-y=0$ has no solution in $\Bbb{P}^1(K)$ if $char(K)\ne 2$.

Comment: The $(0,0,0…)$ point does not solve all the varieties. Take as an example the one-equation variety $x-1=0$. It does has a solution, but it is not $0$. Maybe the issue is that i formulated it backwards, let me edit…

Comment: Sure but you said homogeneous polynomials

Comment: Oh, if i add a constant term it is not homogeneus anymore?

Comment: Your statement of the Nullstellensatz seems a little off to me. Can you post the full statement and where you got it from?

Comment: Well, I would consider a constant polynomial to be homogeneous of degree 0, and if the constant is nonzero then it can have no roots already just by itself.

Comment: There! I edited already. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: 1. Please use markdown (not MathJax) to format italics - i.e. `*italics*` produces *italics*. 2. Where has this idea that the polynomials need to be homogeneous come from? It sounds to me like you are confusing two different statements/versions of the nullstellensatz.

Comment: Oh, sorry! You’re rigth. Homogeneous is indeed not a condition. I had it wrong. Should i delete?

Comment: Well, actually my question is still not answered, let me edit one last time…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct example is $V(1)$. All other examples are essentially this example, but dressed up in a more interesting way - $V(f_1,\cdots,f_n)=\emptyset$ implies $(f_1,\cdots,f_n)=(1)$, as the Wikipedia page you quote says.

Here's a bunch of other examples:

- $V(x,x-1)$
- $V(x,y,x+y+1)$
- $V(x,y,z,xyz-1)$
- $V(x^2+y^2+1,x^2+y^2+4)$
- and so on...